# What is the difference in working of an GMR readhead vs an EMR one?

Tags: magnetics, hard-drive

As I understand it, a GMR readhead works by stacking magnetic and non magnetic layers, passing a current through them and measuring the **total** resistance. Then a 4 point measurement is used to remove the effects of the borders, like so:[image: GMR readhead]

Now, the schematics of an EMR shows the following:[image: EMR readhead]

I'm assuming that the Au resistor is just normal shunt register that is used to measure the total resistance. So I'm assuming that this is **not** the stack below and what are looking at is only the connection from the 4 pins upwards (which was circuitry in the above figure). So the 4 pins there are the pins as above. Is this correct?

If so, then how can the EMR diagram shown above possibly provide the same functionality as an GMR when the SiN and InSb are insulators and the I- en I+ pins can't even be connected to a source?

If not, then it should be the other way around; the circuitry remains the same, but the stack is replaced by the insulators and the shunt resistors. This doesn't make sense to me as the whole reading mechanism of the stack is now nowhere to be found.

Comment: Based on the assumption that both techniques do actually work then the only point I put to you is about the validity of the diagrams you have presented or your interpretation of them. Have you tried posting on a physics site?

Comment: The diagrams come from my professor. I highly suspect that my interpretation of them is wrong. I figured it too specific for physics.stackx because it's more about the electronical layout of the component. Not about the electromagnetic physics behind them, which I understand.

Comment: @RungeKutta: If you understand the physics behind it, then the layout should make perfect sense, shouldn't it?

Comment: I should have specified: I understand the physics behind an GMR. I lack enough insight into the working of an EMR to know if the same principles are used there. If not, then you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This drawing shows a better overview of the reading head: [image: ERM reading head]

Here you can see that my assumption that they both operated with a stack was completely wrong. The diagrams above where in fact the reading head itself and represent an alternative to the stacked layout. This can be seen by the fact that the Au shunt is in magnetic proximity to the magnetic grain.

So the difference between GMR en EMR is the entire structure of the reading head and underlying physics. They provide the same function (reading of magnetic grains) but GMR uses an alternating series of magnetic and non-magnetic layers to read out while EMR uses a Au shunt resistance separated from the 4-point measurement pins by a InSb barrier.

As @Andy_aka pointed out, the working physics behind this setup depends on knowledge of the materials involved and is perhaps better suited for a physics forum. If the community feels differently about this I will append my answer.